# AS3 - Hiding TileList's background

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, flash-cs6

[image: This Picture Shows The Issue]

I'm using a tileList with a custom ImageCell Class and I would like to hide the grey background behind my M15 & M19 buttons. I've tried setting the background.alpha & opaqueBackground on the ImageCell Class & TileList with no luck...

Any help would be appreciated.

edit2: Add the tilelist setup and the entire custom cell renderer for clarity...

```
//TileList Settings in main class
tilelist.width = 235.53;
tilelist.height = 592;
tilelist.move(14, 118);
tilelist.columnWidth = 220.53;
tilelist.rowHeight = 53;
tilelist.visible = true;
tilelist.direction = ScrollBarDirection.VERTICAL;

tilelist.setStyle("cellRenderer", UserListRenderer);
tilelist.setStyle("contentBackgroundAlpha", 0);

//Custom CellRenderer
package {

    import fl.controls.listClasses.ICellRenderer;
    import fl.controls.listClasses.ImageCell;
    import fl.controls.TileList;
    import flash.text.*;

    public class UserListRenderer extends ImageCell implements ICellRenderer {

        public function UserListRenderer() {

            //inherit the variables from the parent
            super();

            //we don't want to stretch our images to fit the size of the box
            loader.scaleContent = true;

            //change the cursor as if this was a button
            useHandCursor = true;
        }

        override public function set data(data:Object):void
        {
            super.data = data;

            // Set the default skin to be invisible. This is a bit
            // easier than creating a new skin, if your goal is
            // to hide the white background.

            this.setStyle("contentBackgroundAlpha", 0);
        }

        /**
        * Now we override the function that draws the layout
        * so we can move the image beside the text
        **/
        override protected function drawLayout():void 
        {
            //adjust the icon for any existing padding
            var imagePadding:Number = getStyleValue("imagePadding") as Number;

            //offset the image in the box so it's not touching the top of it
            loader.move(1, 0);

            var h:Number = height-(imagePadding*2);*/

            var w:Number = width + (imagePadding*2);
            var h:Number = height + (imagePadding*2);

            if (loader.width != w && loader.height != h) {
                loader.setSize(w,h);
            }

            //re-draw the image
            loader.drawNow();

            //hide the original cellImage textField so we can display our new one later
            textField.visible = false;

            //adjust the background
            background.width = width;
            background.height = height;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest grabbing flex spy and dropping it into your project (just have to copy in the SWC and I believe it's one line).  This should help you to pinpoint the graphic element that's drawing the grey background (it works similar to Chrome's inspect).

Comment: I can't seem to get flexspy to play nice with AS3... Flash Builder finds it fine but when I go to compile it can't find it.

Comment: if you can't get this working or find an answer I suggest posting a new question.  That said, if this occurs sometimes an internal error occurred in FB and it's failing silently, try to clean build the project, also try restarting FB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Flex:

```
list.setStyle("contentBackgroundAlpha", 0)
```

or if the app is perfomance critical, build a custom skin

For Flash Pro:

Double-Click the List on stage to change the current skin, or create a new skin and assign it with

```
list.setStyle("skin", SkinName) //SkinName is a MovieClip in the library
```

Comment: I've tried this in several places with no joy... I've tried it in the set data function (as above) in the drawlayout function and on the object itself tilelist.setStyle("contentBackgroundAlpha", 0); Am I just failing to place it in the right spot?

Comment: Setting it this way works, I am sure, since I have done it 14 minutes ago :) 

Have tried building a custom skin and simply removed the complete background ?

Comment: Heh. I agree it should be solving my issue but for some reason it isn't... I posted up my custom class for clarity on the chance I'm doing something bone headed in there. I'll have to look into building a custom skin next.

Comment: Do you want to remove the background of a CELL or the background of the LIST ?

Comment: The white/grey background in the tilelist. I just can't seem to make it disappear. I posted up the custom cell renderer because some sites listed that as causing the white background. :/

Comment: Yes and no. You normally have a background in each cell. But you have an additional background in the list itself. So, just out of curiosity, please try list.setStyle("contentBackgroundColor", 0xff0000) and see what happens

Comment: Done, but the change had no effect.

Comment: I'm using Flash Pro for layout and Flash Builder for writing AS3 code.

Comment: Okay, then why don´t you just double-click the tile list you are using and change the current skin. Because the is obviously no way to change the style by code. At least no "clean" way.

Comment: Unfortunately the tilelist is not in the Flash Pro layout because of how it's used throughout the app.

Comment: The app breaks down into 3 separate pieces and the tilelist is used in all of them. I add the tilelist to each piece where I need it... So it doesn't live on just one form and that's why I created it via AS3.

Comment: So, simply edit the MovieClip for the skin. easiest way. Located in the "Component Assets"-Folder in the library

Comment: It's not available to the library I add it in via AS3 & addChild on the fly where needed.

Comment: It has to be in the library, otherwise, how would you attach it?

You can attach it afterwards, but it has to be in the lib, so that Flash knows, what you are talking about, when you call var l:TileList = new TileList() :) 

Or you doing something that I do COMPLETELY not understand :)

Comment: Misread that... I thought you were saying the tilelist itself in the Library. Editing the skin in Flash Pro got it. Wewt. Thanks for all the help, I wish I could upboat you more.